# to initialize fault tolerant connection,remote server returned error

Tags: tibco, ems

Am getting below error while adding `EMS` as in `FT mode`. I have mentioned EMS server name as "EMS-SERVER" in `tibemsd.conf` file.  Can you please tell me from where `"E4EMS-SERVER"` value is taking???

> ERROR: Server failed to recover state.WARNING: Unable to initialize
>   fault tolerant connection,remote server returned 'The primary EMS
>   server name is E4EMS-SERVER while the standby EMS server name is
>   EMS-SERVER. The names must be the same

Thanks
Lijo

Comment: Perhaps it would easier for others to help you, if you elaborate a little more on 1. what exactly you want to achieve, 2. which software/ configuration/ environment you are using and 3. what you have already tried

Comment: I am trying to setup my EMS in FT Mode, I have configured all the parameters in the 2 EMS config files. But I am getting above error.

Answer (score 3):

Fault tolerance implies that you are setting up two EMS instances in a fault-tolerant pair.  There is a requirement that the server name be exactly the same in ***both*** `tibemsd.conf` configuration files.  In your case it appears that one file has the name as `"EMS-SERVER"` while the other has the name as `"E4EMS-SERVER"`.

Comment: EMS server name is given as same in both files 

server                  = EMS-SERVER
password                = 
        
######################################################################## ########################################################################

server                  = EMS-SERVER
password                = 
        
Is there any reference in any other files?